# If the cookie is cleared, will the session destroy in php?

Tags: php, session, cookies

After logging in a PHP web application and then clear the cookie in inspect element,  will the session destroy?? If so,why?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: ^ a *novel* idea.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: if you lock your front door and throw away the key - will the building collapse?

Comment: How can you clear a cookie by inspecting an element? By the way, I wouldn't use a session cookie for login unless sensitive data is being handled, people generally get annoyed at having to log in every time they close and reopen their browser to go to your website.

Answer (score 0):

By default php will use a cookie to track a user across page views.

When the page is requested, the session cookie is included, the server matches the session cookie value to a session and then makes the session information available in php when generating a response.

If you delete the cookie in web inspector / console, it can no longer be included with the request and the session will not be matched.

The session still exists on the server until the garbage collection process removes it, but without that cookie, it will never me matched.